# button not firing in datatable

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I have created a table using the datatable jquery plugin.
Following is the json used

```
{
"aaData":[{
"Month": "Jan-2013",
"Comments": "",
"Details": " <button class='dialog-link'>View</button>"
}]
}
```

So as expected a button is created.

Then i put some jquery operation on this

```
 $(".dialog-link").click(function (event) {
    console.log("clicked");
    window.open('details.aspx', 'winname', 'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=850,height=650');
    return false;
});
```

This function is not working...no error are coming in debug but the parent window get refreshed and no child window(details.aspx) is opened....whats wrong here

Comment: does .dialog-link generated after page load..?? if yes then you must use .on jquery function...such as $(".dialog-link").on('click',function (event) {

Comment: $(".dialog-link").on('click', function (event) {
        alert("clicked");
    }); this also not working

Comment: use event.preventDefault(); or event.stopPropagation();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, instead:

```
$(document).on('click', ".dialog-link", function (event) {
    console.log("clicked");
    window.open('details.aspx', 'winname', 'directories=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=850,height=650');
    return false;
});
```

.click() has an annoying tendency not to work with elements that have been dynamically added to the DOM after the page load event is done. That's one of the reasons that .click, and .bind and .live are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.dialog-link', function() { ... });
```

Attach an event handler to a parent element using .on(), and pass the selector as an argument.